# Building Android Login with PHP and mysql

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, authentication

i've created my android login with connection to my PHP and mysql, the thing is, every time i run my program and inputting the right email and password it always says  android.os.NetworkOnMainException in my EditText, or when i'm deleting the code for that nothing happens. Did i made mistakes in my codings or am i missing something. Okay, this are my codes guys.

Android:

**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
     EditText inputEmail ;
    EditText inputPassword ;
    Button btnLogin ;
    public void validation()
    {
        if(inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("") || inputPassword.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Fill Empty Fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }
        else
        {
            connectphp();
        }
        }
    public void connectphp()
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eadd", inputEmail.getText().toString()));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", inputPassword.getText().toString()));
    //Passing Parameter to the php web service for authentication
    //String valid = "1";
    String response = null;
    try {
    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/TheCalling/log_in.php", postParameters);  //Enter Your remote PHP,ASP, Servlet file link
    String res=response.toString();
    res = res.trim();
    res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    //error.setText(res);
    if(res.equals("1"))
    {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Correct Username or Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainMenu.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
        else
            if(res.equals("0"))
        {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        inputEmail.setText(e.toString());
    }}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.login);
 inputEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
 inputPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v)
{ 
    validation(); 
    //(This is to check empty fields)
}
});
}}
```

**

By the way, this codes was from here in stack overflow also.

CustomHttpClient

**

```
public class CustomHttpClient {
/** The time it takes for our client to timeout */
public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds
/** Single instance of our HttpClient */
private static HttpClient mHttpClient;
/**
 * Get our single instance of our HttpClient object.
 *
 * @return an HttpClient object with connection parameters set
 */
private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
    if (mHttpClient == null) {
        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    }
    return mHttpClient;
}
/**
 * Performs an HTTP Post request to the specified url with the
 * specified parameters.
 *
 * @param url The web address to post the request to
 * @param postParameters The parameters to send via the request
 * @return The result of the request
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static String executeHttpPost(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
        request.setEntity(formEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();
        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
/**
 * Performs an HTTP GET request to the specified url.
 *
 * @param url The web address to post the request to
 * @return The result of the request
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(url));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();
        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**

and my PHP code.

**

```
<?php
include("db_config.php");
$eadd=addslashes($_POST['eadd']);
$password=addslashes($_POST['password']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE eadd='$eadd' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1)
    {
    echo "1";
    //(If result found send 1 to android)
    }
else
    {
    echo "0";
    //(If result not found send o to android)
    }
?>
```

**

Thank you guys for your time.

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new code. They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated. Try to use PDO  for DB connections. Also, take a visit over to bobby table: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Android, strict mode is enabled by default. Basically what this means is that you cannot perform network operations on the UI thread because then they freeze up the app and make it look buggy; thus you get `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

In order to avoid this, use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), which will let you run the download code on a different thread. The documentation shows how to make a subclass and then how to run it (you would run it when your button is clicked).

Comment: Supplementary info on NetworkOnMainThreadException: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html